# How to download large Json data into CSV file in Java?

Tags: java, json, csv

I am new to Java web application. I tried below link for converting `JSON` array of data to `CSV` file http://jsfiddle.net/JXrwM/11322/

Now the issue is, whenever getting large amount of `JSONArray` of value, unable to convert `CSV` file as soon as possible. Loading time is too long.

Fetching `JSONArray` like below,

```
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(P_CURSOR);
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
while (rs.next()) {
       JSONObject data = new JSONObject();           
       data.put(LASTNAME, rs.getString(LASTNAME));
       data.put(FIRSTNAME, rs.getString(FIRSTNAME));
       jsonArr.put(data); //**Fetching JSONArray is too slow.**
}
```

Here the `data` contains multiple records, how to fetch `jsonArr` faster and download into **CSV** file from `ResultSet` data.

Comment: Can you define "too slow"? Can you define the speed you want?

Comment: What does this have to do with CSV?

Comment: @S Jade if CSV file has more than 2000 record its too slow, Else CSV downloading within 5Secs.

Comment: @dainu i am getting multiple data in `jsonArr`. ex: 10000*[{"Vehicle":"BMW","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Location":"Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Speed":42}] (i.e) 10000 times of row. So the loading time of fetching `jsonArr` takes 5-10mins. How to resolve fetching time?

Comment: A) dont put more information into comments B) "downloading" is for sure the wrong word. You are reading data from the database, and you want to simply **write** that data into a CSV file, right?

Comment: This question is architecturally unclear and depends on unspecified factors. In addition, it seems it contains two separate questions: how to _speed up _ a process and how to implement it differently.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for spending your valuable time, i tried with resultset as you said. But writing data from database to CSV all the data are showing in single cell. Unable to separate into new rows.

Comment: @Roberto Lo Giacco i was confused to convert CSV from either JSONArray or ResultSet. Provide me some suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for write large data in `json` format from `resultset` using **Jackson library** like below,

```
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(P_CURSOR);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        JsonFactory jsonfactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonfactory.createJsonGenerator(writer);

        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        while (rs.next()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField(KEY1, rs.getString(KEY1));
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField(KEY2, rs.getString(KEY2));
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField(KEY3, rs.getString(KEY3));
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }

        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
        jsonGenerator.close();
```

This helps to read and write large set of data from `resultset` with less loading time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be that you are doing a "full" read, and then a "full" write to the CSV file.

Meaning: your code *first* reads all the data into a single `ResultSet` instance, and that big object is then send to a CSVWriter in one shot.

*Maybe* the answer is to rework your whole code to do that for *rows*, one by one.

Meaning:

- you setup your CSVWriter
- you fetch *one* row from the database
- you write *one* line using the CSVWriter

Coming from such a solution, you might be able to use different threads for producing and consuming that data. As in: one thread reads single lines, and puts that data on some "queue", and another thread reads from that queue, to write CSV data.

Most likely, that is the only way that would enable you to speed up overall execution time. Of course, using multiple threads will only pay out if there is really enough data to process.